# Error encountered when generating numbers in series

Tags: django, python-3.x

In every post that will be posted by user, I want number to be generated from Integer field in series. I have encountered the error named "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'"

How would I get rid off this error?

views.py

```
 @login_required
def Claim(request):
    max_val = Documents.objects.all().aggregate(Max('pay_no'))

    # then just make new object, and assign max+1 to 'that_field_in_question'
    control_number = Documents(pay_no=max_val + 1)
    control_number.save()

    return render(request,"loststuffapp/claim.html",context={"documents":Documents.objects.all()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the dictionary:

```
@login_required
def Claim(request):
    max_val = Documents.objects.aggregate(max_no=Max('pay_no'))['max_no'] or 0

    # then just make new object, and assign max+1 to 'that_field_in_question'
    control_number = Documents(pay_no=max_val + 1)
    control_number.save()

    return render(request, 'loststuffapp/claim.html', context={'documents':Documents.objects.all()})
```

In case there are no objects, `Max(..)` will return `None`, so by using `or 0`, we will in that case use `0` instead.

I would however advice *not* to do this, since for example it is possible that two (or more) requests are processed simultaneously, in which case, both will be given the *same* `pay_no`. You better use an [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) here, or just use the primary key.

Comment: So if I use AutoField no need to increment by 1 when aggregating??

Comment: @Kelvin: exactly. Usually that i implemented at the database side, and this should guarantee that the ids are dispatched correctly. See for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2):

Django `QuerySet.aggregate` returns a dictionary. To get `max_val` you need to access the key generated in the aggregate

```
max_val = Documents.objects.all().aggregate(Max('pay_no'))['pay_no__max']
```